How to get dynamic html source code for hidden div with python? (Selenium + beautifulsoup issues)
I want to load a html page using selenium.
This is my python code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()

text_file = open(r'<my_path>', 'w')
text_file.write(soup.prettify())
text_file.close()

The code part that I'm interested in my saved .txt file is empty:
<div class="sh-share-analysis">
    <h2>
        Analysten-Meinung
    </h2>
    <div class="content sh-hidden" data="1">
        <div class="bar sh-hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="value sh-hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="tab sh-hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="sh-link sh-hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <span>
          Zur Detailanalyse
         </span>
        </a>
     </div>

And this is how it looks in my dev tools, when I load the page in the browser:
<div class="sh-share-analysis">
    <h2>Analysten-Meinung</h2>
    <div class="content" data="1">
        <div class="bar">
        <div class="action-30" style="width: 49.5%;"></div><div class="action-20" style="width: 49.5%;"></div></div>
        <div class="value">
        <div class="action-30"><div class="bullet"></div>Positiv (1)</div><div class="action-20"><div class="bullet"></div>Neutral (1)</div></div>
        <div class="tab">
        <div><span>Ø Kursziel (geschätzt)</span><span>160,91 EUR</span></div><div><span>Differenz zum Kurs</span><span>+12,82 %</span></div></div>
        <div class="sh-link sh-hidden">
            <a href="https://wertpapiere.ing.de/Investieren/Aktie/Analyse/US0079031078" wtevent=""><span>Zur Detailanalyse</span></a>
        </div>


You can try to get all text from this div using XPATH (page_source can't load dynamic source):
 WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div')),
                f'Exception get element').text

A 15 second timer will help you wait for dynamic elements to load
